# ARKit App Crashes on launch with appstore review, not on device

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

The appstore review team told me that the app was crashing on launch.

I believe the app was crashing at didFinishLaunching:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    guard ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {
        fatalError("""
            ARKit is not available on this device. For apps that require ARKit
            for core functionality, use the `arkit` key in the key in the
            `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` section of the Info.plist to prevent
            the app from installing. (If the app can't be installed, this error
            can't be triggered in a production scenario.)
            In apps where AR is an additive feature, use `isSupported` to
            determine whether to show UI for launching AR experiences.
        """) // For details, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit
    }

    return true
}
```

However, the app can only be installed on a device which supports ARKit, so I am not sure how apple was able to replicate this on a iOS13 device, as the UIRequiredDeviceCapability includes an ARKit entry in the .plist. Is it possible they are running the app on a device without this capability? Is the app actually crashing because of the fatalerror call?

Here is the crashlog that I was only partially able to symbolicate:

```
Date/Time:           2019-10-06 13:10:04.9570 -0700
Launch Time:         2019-10-06 13:10:04.7508 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.1.2 (17A860)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    9.00.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a62abefc
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [561]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a62abefc 0x1a609e000 + 2154236
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a62abefc 0x1a609e000 + 2154236
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a60c764c 0x1a609e000 + 169548
3   ARC2500A                        0x0000000100fcc6c8 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 83656 (AppDelegate.swift:0)
4   UIKitCore                       0x000000019cf76ebc 0x19c590000 + 10383036
5   UIKitCore                       0x000000019cf78c8c 0x19c590000 + 10390668
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000019cf7e4c0 0x19c590000 + 10413248
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019c75a810 0x19c590000 + 1878032
8   UIKitCore                       0x000000019cbeb3ec 0x19c590000 + 6665196
9   UIKitCore                       0x000000019c75b2f8 0x19c590000 + 1880824
10  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c75ae04 0x19c590000 + 1879556
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c75b124 0x19c590000 + 1880356
12  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c75a9e0 0x19c590000 + 1878496
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c75eefc 0x19c590000 + 1896188
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000019cb1e028 0x19c590000 + 5824552
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000019cc045ac 0x19c590000 + 6768044
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c75ec34 0x19c590000 + 1895476
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000019cc044a8 0x19c590000 + 6767784
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c75eaa0 0x19c590000 + 1895072
19  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c5d3efc 0x19c590000 + 278268
20  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c5d2a64 0x19c590000 + 272996
21  UIKitCore                       0x000000019c5d3c34 0x19c590000 + 277556
22  UIKitCore                       0x000000019cf7c840 0x19c590000 + 10405952
23  UIKitCore                       0x000000019cb3ea0c 0x19c590000 + 5958156
24  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e00b994 0x19dfff000 + 51604
25  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e030960 0x19dfff000 + 203104
26  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e0160f8 0x19dfff000 + 94456
27  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e03061c 0x19dfff000 + 202268
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198c40184 0x198be4000 + 377220
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198be9038 0x198be4000 + 20536
30  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e055540 0x19dfff000 + 353600
31  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e05520c 0x19dfff000 + 352780
32  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019e055734 0x19dfff000 + 354100
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198ef07e0 0x198e47000 + 694240
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198ef0738 0x198e47000 + 694072
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198eefed0 0x198e47000 + 691920
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198eeb01c 0x198e47000 + 671772
37  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198eea8bc 0x198e47000 + 669884
38  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a2d56328 0x1a2d53000 + 13096
39  UIKitCore                       0x000000019cf806d4 0x19c590000 + 10421972
40  ARC2500A                        0x0000000100fc3010 main + 45072 (TableVC.swift:13)
41  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000198d75460 0x198d74000 + 5216

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198d6acb4 0x198d46000 + 150708
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c88d8c 0x198c84000 + 19852
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c88d5c 0x198c84000 + 19804
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198ecc2f4 0x198e47000 + 545524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198ecb4dc 0x198e47000 + 541916
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198c3f610 0x198be4000 + 374288
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198c40184 0x198be4000 + 377220
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198bf5104 0x198be4000 + 69892
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198bf579c 0x198be4000 + 71580
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c8ff64 0x198c84000 + 48996
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c92ae0 0x198c84000 + 60128

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c92ad8 0x198c84000 + 60120

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c92ad8 0x198c84000 + 60120

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c92ad8 0x198c84000 + 60120

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198d495f4 0x198d46000 + 13812
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198d48a60 0x198d46000 + 10848
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198ef0068 0x198e47000 + 692328
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198eeb188 0x198e47000 + 672136
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000198eea8bc 0x198e47000 + 669884
5   Foundation                      0x000000019922a994 0x199223000 + 31124
6   Foundation                      0x000000019922a874 0x199223000 + 30836
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019d01849c 0x19c590000 + 11043996
8   Foundation                      0x000000019935b0b0 0x199223000 + 1278128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c8f1ec 0x198c84000 + 45548
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c92aec 0x198c84000 + 60140

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c92ad8 0x198c84000 + 60120

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198c92ad8 0x198c84000 + 60120

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x8000000100fd0130   x1: 0x0000000000000407   x2: 0x0000000000000407   x3: 0x000000000000002b
    x4: 0x0000000107f05230   x5: 0x0000000000000026   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000c70
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x00000000000295b0  x10: 0x00000000000d29d0  x11: 0x0000000000179f41
   x12: 0x0000000107f04000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0x00000000b71ada31  x15: 0x000000000000080c
   x16: 0x0000000198c7e040  x17: 0x000000000000080c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000100fd0142
   x20: 0x0000000000000002  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000014  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x8000000100fd0130  x25: 0x000000000000000b  x26: 0xd0000000000001cb  x27: 0x0000000000000051
   x28: 0x00000001dc5d1000   fp: 0x000000016ee455d0   lr: 0x00000001a62abefc
    sp: 0x000000016ee45550   pc: 0x00000001a62abefc cpsr: 0x60000000
   esr: 0xf2000001  Address size fault
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an important note from the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923553-issupported) for the `isSupported` property.

> **Discussion**
>
> Different types of AR experiences (which you configure using concrete
>   ARConfiguration subclasses) can have different hardware requirements.
>
> Before attempting to create an AR configuration, verify that the
>   user’s device supports the configuration you plan to use by checking
>   the isSupported property of the corresponding configuration class. If
>   this property’s value is false, the current device does not support
>   the requested configuration.
>
> **Important**
>
> All ARKit configurations require an iOS device with an A9 or later
>   processor. If your app otherwise supports other devices and offers
>   augmented reality as a secondary feature, use this property to
>   determine whether to offer AR-based features to the user.
>
> If your app requires ARKit for its core functionality, use the arkit
>   key in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities section of your app's
>   Info.plist to make your app available only on devices that support
>   ARKit.

Conclusively, this means that the test device used by Apple Store Review **does not support `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` subclass of `ARConfiguration`**. Probably they use a device with below an A9 processor or they used an iOS version older than 11.0 to test the app.

Otherwise,

In the Info.plist, make sure in your `UIRequiredDeviceCapability`, you have the `arkit` entry all in small caps.

Comment: Thank you for your response @NSCoder. The crashlog states that they are using iOS13. And yes, I have the arkit entry in the plist for UIRequiredDeviceCapability. How would they install the app on a device which does not support it, and for what reason? The scenario should not happen in production. Is it for sure crashing at the fatalerror call according to the crashlog or is the issue elsewhere?